# AWS RDS Performance Insights not showing TOP SQL Queries

Tags: amazon-rds

I don't see the SQL query in the top SQL of Performance Insights on RDS. If you know the cause, please let me know.
I set up a service that was released about 4 days ago, so access is always available.
I have RDS Full access with IAM permissions, so the permissions don't seem to matter.